# How do I get my Disciplines to appear in published Site (in EPF Composer 1.5)?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, methodology

I have a custom category ("disciplines") in my method plugin which I want to use to contain existing disciplines (from the Scrum plugin and EPF OpenUP library) as well as a few of my own (some are new, and others extend the OpenUP ones). I can add them simply, order them as desired, and view them in the Browsing Perspective and Preview tab.

However, when I publish, I cannot see the disciplines I have added or extended. There are no errors in the publish logs and the warnings I have refer to other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom disciplines and extensions must contain tasks. When you add some, they will be visible upon publishing.